# Refreshing UI parts on each loop of an AJAX sync call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, user-interface

Okay, it might be a simple question, but so far I didn't find anything helpful by searching, so I am giving it a try here.

I am using plain old javascript/jquery on asp.net core on some project I am working on.

I am currently performing some actions on some employees in a foreach loop.
For each employee I am calling synchronously via ajax an API.

What I want is the UI to be updated, showing the current employee being processed in a progress bar.

While on debug, the process seems to work fine, but during normal process, it seems that the UI thread is not updated, only after all the work has been done. As such, as soon as I start processing the employees, the screen is stuck and closes after the work has been done. No progress bar is shown.

I only managed to show the progress animation and the first employee using the below trick

```
$('#applyYes').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var year = $('#yearCombo').val();

   $('#applyInfo').hide();
   $('#applyLoad').show();
   $('#applyAction').prop('innerText', 'Calculating...');

   setTimeout(function () {

      var employeeIDs = multipleEmployees_Array();
      for (var i = 1; i <= employeeIDs.length; i++) {
         employeeID = employeeIDs[i - 1];
         applyAmount(employeeID, year); //1. Updates progress bar 2. Ajax sync call
      }

   }, 0);
```

})

As far as I understand the e.preventDefault seems to move the timeout function being processed after UI thread finishes.

What is the optimal way of achieving what I want?

PS: No external libraries if possible. I am working on an third-party platform, that makes it difficult to add external libraries (policies, permissions etc.)

Comment: This is why a) you shouldn't use synchronous AJAX calls (it blocks the UI from being updated) and b) make AJAX calls in a loop. To fix the problem I would strongly suggest you make a single async AJAX call which retrieves all staff data. This will keep the UI alive, and also reduce the stress on your server.

Comment: To clarify some points:  the `e.preventDefault` stops the default click event happening - if it's an `<a>` stops it navigating, if it's a `<button type='submit'` stops it submitting.  That's all.  The `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)` is used to "continue" processing after the event has completed.  That part is not asynchronous, it does not run in the background, it just runs after.  Javascript is single threaded.  You can only have 1 piece of code running at a time, and that includes UI "updates".  So if your code is currently off running an http request, it can't update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous HTTP requests are deprecated for precisely this reason. Don't use them.

Use Asynchronous requests instead.

If you want to run them sequentially then either:

- Trigger `i+1` in `i`'s success function *or*
- Use a Promise based API and `await` the results